# Any jQuery plugin that can display Windows 8 live tile effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I am just wondering how can I slide pictures on a tile from bottom to top and with easing effect (as you can see in win8, the sliding speed is not constant.) Any code and demo would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is. Take a look at [Metro-JS](http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs). It has 'live tiles' and many other Metro UI features.

Answer (score 0):

[windows8-animations](https://github.com/SaraSoueidan/windows8-animations) is another good option.